# How to use same port twice in Python

Tags: python, sockets, networking

Even with the REUSEADDR option, I still cannot reuse the same set of ports. It gives me a 98, "address already in use" error.

Is there a way to kill the first group of sockets before the second group, or fix this?

In the code below, I'm doing the exact same thing twice.

```
servers = []
port_list = [i for i in range(40007, 40107)]
for port in port_list:
    ds = ('', port)
    server = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
    server.setsockopt(socket.SOL_SOCKET, socket.SO_REUSEADDR, 1)
    server.bind(ds)
    server.listen(1)
    servers.append(server)

found,_,_ = select.select(servers, [], [])
found = found[0]
conn, addr = found.accept()
print 'Connected by', addr
data = conn.recv(1024)
print "received", data
conn.sendall("message!!")

conn.close()



#time.sleep(10) # even this doesn't work


port_list = [i for i in range(40007, 40107)]
for port in port_list:
    ds = ('', port)
    server = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
    server.setsockopt(socket.SOL_SOCKET, socket.SO_REUSEADDR, 1)
    server.bind(ds)
    server.listen(1)
    servers.append(server)

found,_,_ = select.select(servers, [], [])
found = found[0]
conn, addr = found.accept()
print 'Connected by', addr

data = conn.recv(1024)
print "received", data
conn.sendall("message!!")
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to close your server sockets after you're done with them. `SO_REUSEADDR` doesn't let you use the address of an *open* socket, only one that has been recently closed but is still lingering in the `TIME_WAIT` state.

Comment: How exactly do I kill all 100 server sockets? (If that's what you mean). I'm doing conn.close() once, for the accepted connection.

Comment: I tried for server in servers: server.close() and that doesn't work.

Comment: Loop through the server sockets and `.close()` them as well.

Comment: @Jobs: That's a different error. You never empty your `servers` list between the two bits so you're probably trying to `select` on an old socket.

Answer (score 1):

Try something like this -- SO_REUSEPORT vs SO_REUSEADDR and you were appending into the same server list. Does it work for you ?

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
import os
import sys 
import socket
import select

while True:
    servers = []
    port_list = [i for i in range(40007, 40107)]
    for port in port_list:
        ds = ('', port)
        server = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
        server.setsockopt(socket.SOL_SOCKET, socket.SO_REUSEPORT, 1)
        server.bind(ds)
        server.listen(1)
        servers.append(server)

    f,_,_ = select.select(servers, [], []) 
    for found in f:
        conn, addr = found.accept()
        print 'Connected by', addr
        data = conn.recv(1024)
        print "received", data
        conn.sendall("message!!\n")
        conn.close()


    #time.sleep(10) # even this doesn't work

    servers = []
    port_list = [i for i in range(40007, 40107)]
    for port in port_list:
        ds = ('', port)
        server = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
        server.setsockopt(socket.SOL_SOCKET, socket.SO_REUSEPORT, 1)
        server.bind(ds)
        server.listen(1)
        servers.append(server)

    f,_,_ = select.select(servers, [], []) 
    for found in f:
        conn, addr = found.accept()
        print 'Connected by -- BB', addr
        data = conn.recv(1024)
        print "received --- BB\n", data
        conn.sendall("message!!----BB\n")
        conn.close()
```

Comment: `SO_REUSEPORT` will cause the old servers sockets to remain alive and the connection might "go" to one of them though. Probably an unwanted effect.